# Embedding Bokeh and Big Data in Tkinter GUI

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, bigdata, bokeh, holoviews

I am building a GUI exe application that can display big data around 200 million data points per plot. The only way I have found so far that can remote maintain decent performance is using Bokeh and Holoviews/HVPLOT with Datashade. I have originally built my program using Tkinter to be ran as an executable using Matplotlib/Seaborn visualizations, but that doesn't work performance-wise with plotting big data. I found Bokeh with Datashade can do the job, but is there a way to embed Bokeh/Holoviews into a Tkinter GUI? Bokeh either plots the high resolution charts inside Jupyter Notebook or a lowered resolution version when outputted to a HTML file.

Comment: Note that the resolution when output to an HTML file can be whatever you like if you add an explicit height and width to your `datashade()` or `rasterize()` call (e.g. `height=1000, width=1000`); the HTML output just shows whatever was initially used for the first rendering, which is later updated to the display resolution when run inside Jupyter or Bokeh Server.

Comment: `plot_Z1 = df.hvplot(y='Dataset_A', height=200, datashade=True)`

`plot_Z2 = df.hvplot(y='Dataset_B', height=200, ylim=(-500, 500), datashade=True)`

`plot = (plot_Z1 + plot_Z2.options(shared_axes=True)).cols(1)`

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar I do have dimensions in the call, but these only control the size of the chart in the Jupyter notebook. When I zoom in/out the Datashaded image refreshes itself to load the data points again. However, in the HTML chart outputted to the web browser, it stays at low resolution with missing data points here and there when I do zoom in/out. I'm assuming the dataset doesn't carry over to HTML/browser, but it does inside the Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Right; when you have a live Python process running as in a Jupyter notebook or with Bokeh Server, the full resolution of the data is available in Python, and every time you zoom in a new copy of the image is rendered and passed to the browser.  When you output to HTML, there is no Python running and you will only ever get the initial resolution. But you can control the initial resolution to be whatever you like, at the cost of a larger file size, which can give you some ability to zoom in the exported HTML.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a configuration that's currently supported directly, but you have some options:

1. Is it ok to display just the bare image of a plot, without drawing axes and without overlaying on maps or other types of data?  If so you can use the bare Datashader-only interface shown in the user guide at [datashader.org](http://datashader.org), which lets you generate PNG images that you can easily display in Tkinter.
2. If you do need axes and numerical or text labels, is it ok to render those off-screen into a static PNG that you can display in Tk, without any interactive controls?  If so you can use HoloViews with a Matplotlib backend to render your Datashader plots into a PNG and embed those just as in case 1.  See e.g. the mpl examples in the [Datashader user guide](http://datashader.org/getting_started/3_Interactivity.html).
3. If you do need axes and you need interactive controls (e.g. zoom in and out), there is some [work from 2016 on embedding Datashader into Matplotlib with interactive controls](https://github.com/pyviz/datashader/pull/200). That code hasn't been run in a couple of years and even at the time wasn't mature enough to include in Matplotlib or Datashader directly, but it seems like it could be a starting point for getting Datashader working anywhere Matplotlib has a backend.
4. If approach 3 doesn't work, you could maybe combine approaches 2 and 3 or 1 and 3, showing a static image but manually having zoom/pan/range buttons/widgets in Tkinter that you use to construct a Datashader API call (option 1) or a HoloViews call (option 2). That approach would be more awkard to use, but would let you implement whatever you like.

Hopefully one of these options addresses your needs, and if you come up with anything useful, please let us know in case it might be good to add as an example!